# Name of book series with interlocking cover designs

Tags: publications

I am looking for the name of a series of philosophy books each volume of which introduced and summarized the work a well-known philosopher or other literary figure. I believe the series was published some time between the 60s through the 80s and is now out of print. The series featured covers which combined to form a larger design, similar to [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-c8Uq7uGTIFQ/Ti3fz7XWuVI/AAAAAAAACb4/V-gqxFcj6Rk/s1600/Oliver_Sacks_8.150.jpg) in concept but more abstract in execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have in mind the Fontana 'Modern Masters' series in which Magee wrote on Popper, Wollheim on Freud, Pears on Wittgenstein ...

For example: [https://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30313067584&searchurl=pn%3Dfontana%26bi%3D0%26ds%3D30%26bx%3Doff%26sortby%3D17%26kn%3Dmodern%2Bmasters%26recentlyadded%3Dall&cm_sp=snippet-*-srp1-*-title6](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30313067584&searchurl=pn%3Dfontana%26bi%3D0%26ds%3D30%26bx%3Doff%26sortby%3D17%26kn%3Dmodern%2Bmasters%26recentlyadded%3Dall&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title6)